# How can I re-enable `C-z` in evil mode (to pause Emacs)?

Tags: evil, process, bash, vim-emulation, emacs-nox

I have been using Emacs for a while and recently started using evil mode. I exclusively use emacs-nox (command line emacs).

The only thing that's missing for me is `C-z` to pause emacs and bring me back to my bash shell.

For some reason when evil mode is enabled, the `C-z` hotkey does nothing. When I disable evil mode, `C-z` works just fine. I have never used vi/m before, so I'm not sure if there is a vi/m specific command to pause (I'm pretty `C-z` in vi will pause it as well). I understand that `C-z` is a bash command, not an Emacs hotkey. I'm not sure why it is interrupted by evil mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure why it is interrupted by evil mode.

It's interrupted by evil mode to switch into the "emacs" state, a mode where `evil` falls back into your regular Emacs keybindings:

```lisp
(describe-key "\C-z")
```

> C-z runs the command `evil-emacs-state` (found in `evil-motion-state-map`), which is an interactive compiled Lisp
> function in `‘evil-states.el’`.
>
> It is bound to `C-z`.
>
> ```
> (evil-emacs-state &optional ARG)
> ```
>
> Enable Emacs state. Disable with negative `ARG`. If `ARG` is `nil`,
> don’t display a message in the echo area.

However, `suspend-frame` is also bound to <kbd>C-x C-z</kbd>, see `(describe-function 'suspend-frame)`. This keybinding is *not* changed by evil mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. It was super helpful. I never use `evil-emacs-state`. What would be the best way for me to remap `C-z` to `suspend-frame` in all states?

Comment: Update: to override this keybinding add `(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-z") 'suspend-frame)` to your emacs init file. Thanks again @Zeta!

Answer (score 1):

@Zeta's answer/comment helped me come up with this solution (copied from [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70613619/11319230)):

`C-x C-z` will suspend the frame and return you to the shell.

`C-z` as you mention toggles evil mode on/off.

I swap their behavior in evil like so:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-z") 'suspend-frame)
(define-key evil-emacs-state-map (kbd "C-z") 'suspend-frame)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-x C-z") 'evil-emacs-state)
(define-key evil-emacs-state-map (kbd "C-x C-z") 'evil-exit-emacs-state)
```

See [this commit](https://github.com/bschiela/dotrc/commit/00cef9d45ca147b225dc8ddd170c2f6d0ab62031) for an example (where I also make `C-z` emulate vim-behavior in insert/replace mode).